# Expressing quantities in RDF

Tags: sparql, rdf, turtle-rdf

I want to be able to answer queries like "how many records were created and have log_id 001" or "how many records have been deleted with attribute "00EA".

```
34 records are created with attribute "00EC" and log_id "001"
32 records are updated with attribute "00EC" and log_id "001"
31 records are deleted with attribute "00EC" and log_id "001"

12 records are created with attribute "00EA" and log_id "001"
31 records are updated with attribute "00EA" and log_id "001"
33 records are deleted with attribute "00EA" and log_id "001"

9 records are created with attribute "00EB" and log_id "001"
2 records are updated with attribute "00EB" and log_id "001"
3 records are deleted with attribute "00EB" and log_id "001"

19 records are created with attribute "00EA" and log_id "002"
22 records are updated with attribute "00EA" and log_id "002"
33 records are deleted with attribute "00EA" and log_id "002"
```

Comment: Also asked and answered at http://www.semanticoverflow.com/questions/1997/how-do-i-represent-this-data-as-an-rdf-graph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer you got in ...

http://www.semanticoverflow.com/questions/1997/how-do-i-represent-this-data-as-an-rdf-graph

is pretty good. The only thing to add is that the data you have are statistics and therefore they can be represented as a multi-dimensional structure. A good ontology to represent this type of data is [SCOVO](http://sw.joanneum.at/scovo/schema.html)

So the representation of this record ...

```
[] a :LogEvent;
    :attribute "00EC";
    :log_id "001";
    :records_created 34;
    :records_updated 32;
    :records_deleted 31;
    .
```

could be improved with the following schema level representation ....

```
:LogEvent rdfs:subClassOf scovo:Item .
:records_created rdfs:subPropertyOf scovo:Dimension .
(...)
```

This schema would 'mark up' your data adding extra knowledge about predicates and classes. 
As you add are more data sources into your system you will realize that having it defined at the schema level is very useful to explore it.

Comment: I think you mean :records_created rdfs:subPropertyOf scovo:dimension, or? ;)

Comment: Unfortunately both of the links now 404